# How can salamander-people look like salamanders?

Tags: creature-design, fantasy-races, anatomy, humanoid

Salamanders, like [lizards](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/210021/how-can-lizardmen-be-made-to-seem-lizardly/210022#210022), seem to be quite indistinct. They have very few traits that both distinguish them from other creatures and would be compatible with a typical humanoid being

What visible traits could properly distinguish a humanoid as a salamander, as opposed to a frog or lizard? These traits should not relate to the form of the limbs (above the hands/feet) or torso, which would be humanoid in the salamander people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're just trying to distinguish between frogs, lizards, and salamanders, then this question is relatively straightforward.

Lizards have tails like salamanders, but they also have scaled skin, making them easy to distinguish. Frogs have smooth skin and no tails.

Salamander people would simply have both smooth wet skin and long tails to boot, and that should be enough to make them distinct from both of the other groups. They would also be slender.

As a side note, salamanders are capable of completely regenerating their tails after they are cut off. Lizards can repair them slightly but are usually unable to repair them perfectly. Mentioning this detail briefly might make it more obvious which ones are lizard people and which are salamanders.

It is also important to note that salamanders are distinguished by the fact that they have slender bodies and short snouts. These are features that can easily be incorporated into the designs of a humanoid salamander. Also, they have short limbs jutting out at right angles. Any combination of these features will make your humanoids easy to spot as salamanders. Other features are optional.

Answer (score 3):

Axolotls are a type of salamander, all you need is the iconic gills for 'hair' or something and you're set.

[image]